# How to make this small C# program which calculates prime numbers using the Sieve of Eratosthenes as efficient and economical as possible?

Tags: c#, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've made a small C# program which calculates prime numbers using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
        long n = 100000;

        bool[] p = new bool[n+1];

        for(long i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            p[i]=true;
        }

        for(long i=2; i<=X; i++)
        {
            for(long j=Y; j<=Z; j++)
             {
                p[i*j]=false;
             }
        }

        for(long i=0; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if(p[i])
             {
                 Console.Write(" "+i);
             }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

My question is: which `X`, `Y` and `Z` should I choose to make my program as efficient and economical as possible?

Of course we can just take:

- X = n
- Y = 2
- Z = n

But then the program won't be very efficient.

It seems we can take:

- X = Math.Sqrt(n)
- Y = i
- Z = n/i

And apparently the first 100 primes that the program gives are all correct.

Comment: That looks a lot like the [optimized implementation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (search for "optimized implementation").

Comment: There are fewer than 10,000 primes less than 100,000. Just use a hard-coded table.

Comment: check this http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C.23

Answer (score 1):

There are several optimisations that can be applied without making the program overly complicated.

- you can start the crossing out at j = i (effectively i * i instead of 2 * i) since all lower multiples of i have already been crossed out
- you can save some work by leaving all even numbers out of the array (remembering to produce the prime 2 out of thin air when needed); hence array cell k represents the odd integer 2 * k + 1
- you can make things faster by turning repeated multiplication (i * j) into iterated addition (k += i); instead of looping over j in the inner loop you loop `(k = i * i; k <= N; k += i)`
- in some cases it can be advantageous to initialise the array with 0 (false) and set cells to 1 (true) for composites; its meaning is thus 'is_composite' instead of 'is_prime'

Harvesting all the low-hanging fruit, the loops thus become (in C++, but C# should be sort of similar):

```
uint32_t max_factor_bit = uint32_t(sqrt(double(n))) >> 1;
uint32_t max_bit = n >> 1;

for (uint32_t i = 3 >> 1; i <= max_factor_bit; ++i)
{
   if (composite[i])  continue;

   uint32_t n = (i << 1) + 1;
   uint32_t k = (n * n) >> 1;

   for ( ; k <= max_bit; k += n)
   {
      composite[k] = true;
   }
}
```

Regarding the computation of max_factor there are some caveats where the compiler can bite you, for larger values of n. There's [a topic for that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69069/computing-the-square-root-of-a-64-bit-integer/69074#69074) on Code Review.

A further, easy optimisation is to represent the bitmap as an array of bytes, with each byte standing for eight odd integers. For setting bit k in byte array a you would do `a[k / CHAR_BIT] |= (1 << (k % CHAR_BIT))` where CHAR_BIT is the number of bits in a byte. However, such bit trickery is normally wrapped into an inline function to keep the code clean. E.g. in C++ I tell the compiler how to generate such functions using a template like this:

```
template<typename word_t>
inline
void set_bit (word_t *p, uint32_t index)
{
   enum {  BITS_PER_WORD = sizeof(word_t) * CHAR_BIT  };

   // we can trust the compiler to use masking and shifting instead of division; we cannot do that
   // ourselves without having the log2 which cannot easily be computed as a constexpr

   p[index / BITS_PER_WORD] |= word_t(1) << (index % BITS_PER_WORD);
}
```

This allows me to say `set_bit(a, k)` for any type of array - byte, integer, whatever - without having to write special code or use invocations; it's basically a type-safe equivalent to the old C-style macros. I'm not certain whether something similar is possible in C#. There is, however, the **C#** type `BitArray` where all that stuff is already done for you under the hood.

On pastebin there's a [small demo .cpp for the segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://pastebin.com/UyDSDG3D), where two further optimisations are applied: presieving by small integers, and sieving in small, cache friendly blocks so that the full range of 32-bit integers can be sieved in 2 seconds flat. This could give you some inspiration...

When doing the Sieve of Eratosthenes, memory savings easily translate to speed gains because the algorithm is memory-intensive and it tends to stride all over the memory instead of accessing it locally. That's why space savings due to compact representation (only odd integers, packed bits - i.e. `BitArray`) and localisation of access (by sieving in small blocks instead of the whole array in one go) can speed up the code by one or more orders of magnitude, without making the code significantly more complicated.

It is possible to go far beyond the easy optimisations mentioned here, but that tends to make the code increasingly complicated. One word that often occurs in this context is the 'wheel', which can save a further 50% of memory space. The wiki has [an explanation of wheels here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization), and in a sense the odds-only sieve is already using a 'modulo 2 wheel'. Conversely, a wheel is the extension of the odds-only idea to dropping further small primes from the array, like 3 and 5 in the famous 'mod 30' wheel with modulus 2 * 3 * 5. That wheel effectively stuffs 30 integers into one 8-bit byte.

Here's a runnable rendition of the above code in C#:

```
static uint max_factor32 (double n)
{
   double r = System.Math.Sqrt(n);

   if (r < uint.MaxValue)
   {
      uint r32 = (uint)r;

      return r32 - ((ulong)r32 * r32 > n ? 1u : 0u);
   }

   return uint.MaxValue;
}

static void sieve32 (System.Collections.BitArray odd_composites)
{
   uint max_bit = (uint)odd_composites.Length - 1;
   uint max_factor_bit = max_factor32((max_bit << 1) + 1) >> 1;

   for (uint i = 3 >> 1; i <= max_factor_bit; ++i) 
   {
      if (odd_composites[(int)i])  continue;

      uint p = (i << 1) + 1;  // the prime represented by bit i
      uint k = (p * p) >> 1;  // starting point for striding through the array

      for ( ; k <= max_bit; k += p)
      {
         odd_composites[(int)k] = true;
      }
   }
}

static int Main (string[] args)
{
   int n = 100000000;

   System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, Eratosthenes! Sieving up to {0}...", n);

   System.Collections.BitArray odd_composites = new System.Collections.BitArray(n >> 1);

   sieve32(odd_composites);

   uint cnt = 1;
   ulong sum = 2;

   for (int i = 1; i < odd_composites.Length; ++i)
   {
      if (odd_composites[i])  continue;

      uint prime = ((uint)i << 1) + 1;

      cnt += 1;
      sum += prime;
   }

   System.Console.WriteLine("\n{0} primes, sum {1}", cnt, sum);

   return 0;
}
```

This does 10^8 in about a second, but for higher values of n it gets slow. If you want to do faster then you have to employ sieving in small, cache-sized blocks.

Comment: in C++, is `vector<bool>` still [automatically bit-packed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29#Specialization_for_bool), or has that changed recently?

Comment: I can't afford to buy the standard but all drafts that are available on the 'net still have the old `vector<bool>` clause in them ("23.3.8 Class vector<bool>: To optimize space allocation, a specialization of vector for bool elements is provided"); newer C++ compilers also have a bitset<> template. However, with both you need to be circumspect about which member functions you call how, because of things like bounds checking or inefficiencies due to bit references being created under the hood. Like const-qualified [] access is free but non-const is bounds-checked.

Comment: With a functions like the set_bit() template I showed you have full control over what happens with regard to bounds checking and you are much freer in two regards. The first is the choice of bit access method, like 'manual' bit math as shown or use of specialised CPU instructions via compiler intrinsics, combined with choice of word size (byte, uint32_t, uint64_t...). Different word sizes are optimal in different places. The second is that you are freer in deciding how your bits are stored. You could even house them in a string or in a BigInteger.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. Non-const [] access of a bitset<> is not bounds-checked, it returns a bit reference (which may or may not be bounds-checked); const [] access is efficient as it just returns the value. The standard does not **require** `vector<bool>` to be bit-packed, it only **recommends** it. But it's a good bet that most implementations will use a bit-packed representation since that is the whole point of the specialisation in the first place .

Comment: you probably need your own bit-manipulation code for the bigger wheels, anyway. But for odds only it's so easy to just use vector<bool>...

Comment: It's also excellent for proto-typing, because of all the work that implementers have put into things like bounds-checking. Modern library implementations are simply amazing in that regard, and the programming of sieves tends to offer plenty opportunities for messing up index/type bounds and thus appreciating this excellent debug support.